# Cannot explicitly call operator or accessor and static

Tags: c#, setter

I have two stupid questions :

**The first one :**

I have already asked this and I'm truly sorry to ask it again (even more so because there are a lot of posts about it), but now I really don't understand why that happens even if I read every other post, here is my code :

```
public class PageTitre {
    ...
    public void situation(string s) {
        onglet.get_Range("C11").Value = "(" + s + ")";
    }
}

public class PPE_Process {

    public static PageTitre pageTitre;

    public static void MainProcess() {
        ...
        pageTitre = new PageTitre();
        ...
    }
}

public partial class PPE_Ribbon {
    private void SituationEditBox_TextChanged(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        PPE_Process.pageTitre.situation(SituationEditBox.Text);
    }
}
```

I have tried some other things, like putting situation as a variable of `PageTitre` and having a `get` and a `set`, and

```
private void SituationEditBox_TextChanged(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        PPE_Process.pageTitre.set_situation(SituationEditBox.Text);
    }
```

Or

```
private void SituationEditBox_TextChanged(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        PPE_Process.pageTitre.situation = SituationEditBox.Text;
    }
```

But nothing worked, with the same error: **cannot explicitly call operator or accessor**.

I guess there is a problem with the `static`? If that is the case, here is my second question:

**Second one :**

I read a lot of documentation about it but I really can't understand what is the use of "static"... Is it just so that we can't change the value outside of the class, or something like this? Then, would it really change something if I take off every `static` there is in my code?

Again, I am sorry that you have to answer this question again and again, but I understand a lot better if that is directly related to my code, and not someone answering someone else about some other random code, which has a different problem than mine. :/

**Edit to add more information:**

There shouldn't be any problem with `.Value` or `.get_Range`, as it works on other parts of the code, but 
For `.Value`, here is the information given by Visual Studio:

*void Range.set_Value([object RangeValueDataType = System.Type.Missing], [object value = System.Type.Missing])*

For `.get_Range`: *Excel.Range_Worksheet.get_Range(object Cell1, [object Cell2 = System.Type.Missing])*

For `static`, I still don't really understand all these "instances" things, but I will try to look more, **and add another question** in this forum if I still don't understand after this.

Comment: If you have two questions, then please ask them separately.

Comment: It may be coming from "onglet.get_Range("C11").Value" can you update the details to this ? The error look like Value is a method but hard to tell without details, if Value is a method it should be calle with .Value()

Answer (score 0):

To your first question: I don't see any problem with your call of the method `situation`, maybe the problem is the statement *inside* the method (`get_Range("C11")`)?

To your second question: When you make a variable/property/method `static` it means that it is independent from any instance (object) of the class. Otherwise you couldn't access the property `PPE_Process.pageTitre` without an instance of `PPE_Process`.

Answer (score -1):

Alrighty, I changed nothing in my code but now it works with

```
private void SituationEditBox_TextChanged(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    PPE_Process.pageTitre.situation = SituationEditBox.Text;
}
```

So... I don't know, it was maybe a problem with the build of my solution, but that's pretty fortunate :)